# How to expand the size of the address bar in IE10?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

How to expand the size of the address bar in IE10? There's supposed to be a resizer thingy to the right of the bar but it's not there.

[image]

Comment: what operating system are you on? works for me in win7

Comment: Win7. Does yours looks like mine?

Comment: na dude. does not. what's the version number for your install? obviously, beyond "10"?

Comment: It's 10. What do you mean obviously beyond 10?

Comment: the numbers that come after 10 are the release numbers; typically browsers release more than one version; here's mine: http://dev.bowdenweb.com/ua/browsers/ie/i/ie10/about-ie-10.png